# How do I call 'fit' appropriate arguments before using this estimator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

```
 # predict - Predict class labels for samples in X
 log_reg.predict(X_train).fit
 y_pred = log_reg.predict(X_train).fit

 # predict_proba - Probability estimates
 pred_proba = log_reg.predict_proba(X_train)

 # coef_ - Coefficient of the features in the decision function
 log_reg.coef_
```

NotFittedError: This LogisticRegression instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.

Comment: you need to fit your model on a train set before prediction on a test set.

Answer (score 0):

```
# fit classifier on train data
clf = log_reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
# predict on test data
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
# predict probabilities on test data
pred_proba = clf.predict_proba(X_test)
# coefficient of the features in the decision function
print(clf.coef_)
```

Comment: once I add that, I get the error:TypeError: 'list' object is not callable